# Eclipse Indigo M2E Ignores MAVEN_OPTS in external installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo, m2e

I'm using m2e 1.0.0.20110607-2117 bundled with Eclipse Indigo. I'm referencing external maven installation from Preferences -> Maven -> Installations. External maven installation version is 3.0.4.

I'm experiencing locale problems because my locale is Turkish. So I've modified MAVEN_OPTS in mvn.bat file in this external installation. When I run mvn from command line, maven sees this maven_opts but Indigo doesn't. How can I pass maven_opts to m2e? Is there any way to set a property that all predefined maven run configurations in eclipse like "Maven build", "Maven clean", "Maven install" etc. use?

EDIT:
Also setting MAVEN_OPTS in system path doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way. You can create a file called mavenrc_pre.bat on windows or .mavenrc in your home folder on linux or windows. Currently i'm not sure if m2e honours the settgins in the mavenrc file ...you have to check that.